Why do I get a different result in my integration of a simple problem?

In trying to work the solution out using hyperbolic identities I got $ \sqrt(2)\sin(π -2u)/4$ and not $ \sqrt(2)\sin(2u-π)/4$ as shown in the picture. I have been trying to find where I went wrong for quite some time.
These are my workings:
$\sin(u) = \cos(π/2-u)$
$\cos(π/2-u) = 2\cos^2(π/4-u/2)-1$
Using the identity, $ \sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1$,
$2\cos^2(π/4-u/2)-1 = 1-2\sin^2(π/4-u/2)$
$1 - \sin(u) = 1 - \cos(π/2-u) = 1-(1-2\sin^2(π/4-u/2)) = 2\sin^2((π-2u)/4)$
$\sqrt{1-\sin(u)} = \sqrt{2}\sin((π-2u/4))$

Actually, they are the same:
You start with $1-\sin u=1-\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-u)=2\sin^2(\frac{\pi-2u}{4})$,but it is the same as $1-\sin u=1-\cos(-\frac{\pi}{2}+u)=2\sin^2(\frac{2u-\pi}{4})$.
$$\text{First case:}\int\sin(\frac{2u-\pi}{4})du=-2\cos(\frac{2u-\pi}{4})+C, \text{for}\ 0+2k\pi\leq \frac{2u-\pi}{4}\leq 2\pi+2k\pi,k\in \mathbb{N}$$
$$\text{Second case:}\int\sin(\frac{-2u+\pi}{4})du=2\cos(\frac{-2u+\pi}{4})+C=2\cos(\frac{2u-\pi}{4})+C,\text{for}\ 0+2k\pi\leq \frac{-2u+\pi}{4}\leq 2\pi+2k\pi,k\in \mathbb{Z}$$

Thank you very much, I love you. My brain is frioed

@rainsoupreme You are welcome.

Hey, sorry to disturb again. Actually when I tried to verify the integral of sin((-2u+pi)/4), I got 2cos((-2u+pi)/4) instead of -2cos((-2u+pi)/4)

@rainsoupreme Sorry, my bad, fixed now.

@rainsoupreme Since it takes the square root, we should make sure that they are nonnegative.

No problem!! Thank you anyway
